# How to make links open in a virtual desktop browser instead of the second screen?

Tags: macos, desktop

When I use a monitor with my Mac, it's to watch videos and multitask. I'd have a Chrome window open on my main screen in a virtual desktop and another Chrome window open on the monitor. When I switch to another virtual desktop on my main screen, then open a web link, OSX always opens it in the monitor instead of the other virtual desktop. I interacted with the virtual desktop Chrome window last. How can I choose to open links in the virtual desktop?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't decided by the last interaction, it's decided by window enumeration.

By default, an external link will open in the *first* window opened in a browser. [Last would be more helpful, but that's not how it works.]
The only way to really persuade this to behave is to close all your windows, open one, then move it to the other screen. Then open a second on your main screen.

This behaviour may change after a reboot, when the windows open again. If you find a pattern to this, then it's just easiest to not fight it & move the windows to where you want them visually rather than by the contents of each.

Comment: Well, that's stupid, as it defeats the meaning and intended use of a virtual desktop.

I want the browser links to open in **the current window I'm currently in**.

Comment: It's because the "intended use" of virtual desktops never included using any app on more than one desktop simultaneously.

Comment: How come? Are they "partially virtual" then? It's because Apple, who really should know better at UI design, is doing a poor service to their users. That's why.

Comment: Who knows why they made any given decision? Spaces hasn't been changed since the introduction of fullscreen. Then they played with split screen. Now they've moved on to Stage Manager. All designed for laptops with a single screen, really.

Comment: They haven't made any decision IMO. They simply didn't do the proper QA assurance / testing to virtual desktops; along with to other silly UI "decisions", by the way.

Comment: Well, complaining to me about it about it here isn't going to get it fixed, is it?

Comment: :-) Let's see. At least, it gives the issue some visibility?

Sorry for venting my frustration on you. I should really go on and create a proper bug fix / request for improvement at Apple. And, good luck with that!